# No write failure on an over-allocated sparse file

Tags: filesystems, loop-device, sparse-files

I've been working with sparse files in order to replicate Linux fs permissions on a Windows samba mount an idea from here: https://www.thanassis.space/backup.html.

While testing sparse files though, I've discovered an, interesting, problem wherein a "full" host drive does not reported as a write failure to an application. Instead, when the host drive fills up, the write continues and completes successfully, even though the drive was full.

In order to test this I have the following setup.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  944M  7.1G  12% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   49M  1.7G   3% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G   33M  4.0G   1% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/0
```

I have mounted a 4G partition on `/mnt` on which I will create a 10G sparse file.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# dd of=/mnt/file bs=1G count=0 seek=10
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 3.0097e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

The file is created correctly and takes up no actual space on the partition, however appears to be a 10G file.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# ls -lh /mnt/
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 10G Aug 28 21:10 file
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# du -h /mnt/
0       /mnt/
```

I allocate a file-system in the space and mount it (verified via losetup).

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# mkfs.xfs /mnt/file
meta-data=/mnt/file              isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=655360 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0, sparse=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=2621440, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0

[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# mount /mnt/file /srv/
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# losetup -j /mnt/file
/dev/loop0: [51729]:67 (/mnt/file)
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  945M  7.1G  12% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   49M  1.7G   3% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G   43M  4.0G   2% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/loop0       10G   33M   10G   1% /srv
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]#
```

On this mount point I can write files as normal, indicating it is working correctly.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/srv/init_file bs=1GiB count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 8.22444 s, 131 MB/s
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  945M  7.1G  12% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   49M  1.7G   3% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G  1.1G  3.0G  27% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/loop0       10G  1.1G  9.0G  11% /srv
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# ls -lh /srv/
total 1.0G
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.0G Aug 28 21:19 init_file
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]#
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  945M  7.1G  12% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   49M  1.7G   3% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G  1.1G  3.0G  27% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/loop0       10G  1.1G  9.0G  11% /srv
```

Now, when I attempt to create a file that should overrun the host drive, it will also write correctly and not report an error.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/srv/too_large_a_file bs=1GiB count=4
4+0 records in
4+0 records out
4294967296 bytes (4.3 GB) copied, 49.9905 s, 85.9 MB/s
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# echo $?
0
```

Relevant data:

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  949M  7.1G  12% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   49M  1.7G   3% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G  4.0G   20K 100% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/loop0       10G  5.1G  5.0G  51% /srv
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# du -h /srv/
5.0G    /srv/
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# du -h /srv/*
1.0G    /srv/init_file
4.0G    /srv/too_large_a_file
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# ls -lh /srv/
total 5.0G
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.0G Aug 28 21:19 init_file
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.0G Aug 28 21:24 too_large_a_file
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]#
```

I attempted to replicate this behavior using other utilities such as `rsync` and `cp`. The also do not report an error, and instead fail silently.

Using cp:

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# cp -v too_large_a_file /srv/
‘too_large_a_file’ -> ‘/srv/too_large_a_file’
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# echo $?
0
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# ls -lhtr /srv/
total 5.0G
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5.0G Aug 28 21:31 too_large_a_file
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  6.0G  2.1G  75% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   57M  1.7G   4% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G  4.0G   20K 100% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/loop0       10G  5.1G  5.0G  51% /srv
```

Using rsync:

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# rsync -vvv too_large_a_file /srv/
[sender] make_file(too_large_a_file,*,0)
send_file_list done
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=16569
received 1 names
recv_file_list done
get_local_name count=1 /srv/
generator starting pid=16569
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
recv_generator(too_large_a_file,0)
send_files(0, too_large_a_file)
send_files mapped too_large_a_file of size 5368709120
calling match_sums too_large_a_file
too_large_a_file
sending file_sum
false_alarms=0 hash_hits=0 matches=0
sender finished too_large_a_file
send_files phase=1
recv_files(1) starting
generate_files phase=1
recv_files(too_large_a_file)
got file_sum
renaming .too_large_a_file.CwVApY to too_large_a_file
recv_files phase=1
generate_files phase=2
send_files phase=2
send files finished
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=5368709120
recv_files phase=2
generate_files phase=3
recv_files finished
generate_files finished

sent 5369364558 bytes  received 31 bytes  57426359.24 bytes/sec
total size is 5368709120  speedup is 1.00
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1052): about to call exit(0)
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  6.0G  2.1G  75% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   73M  1.7G   5% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G  4.0G   20K 100% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/loop0       10G  5.1G  5.0G  51% /srv
```

Upon running `md5sum` I am even more confused:

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# md5sum /root/too_large_a_file
ec4bcc8776ea04479b786e063a9ace45  /root/too_large_a_file
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# md5sum /srv/too_large_a_file
ec4bcc8776ea04479b786e063a9ace45  /srv/too_large_a_file
```

It appears the full file is preserved, although how, I have no idea.

In researching this, I found this question where someone was doing the same thing but using an encrypted setup, they identified the same problem but were unable to solve it (in fact they recommended it be opened a as a new question!): [Creating a grow-on-demand encrypted volume with LUKS](https://serverfault.com/questions/696554/creating-a-grow-on-demand-encrypted-volume-with-luks).

Any help would be great.

**Edit**: Per request the kernel and system information

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-61-147 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 12 15:04:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

Based on the provided answer I created new files to test the `/dev/zero` theory. I created a file with all ones and attempted to replicate my findings and found it was still successful.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# tr '\0' '\377' < /dev/zero | dd bs=1 count=5G of=~/too_large_a_file
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# du -h too_large_a_file
982M    too_large_a_file
```

I then put multiple copies of that file on the sparse-file mount (e.g. `cp too_large_a_file /srv/too_large_a_file_1`)

I was able to copy six of those files onto the external with none of the copies failing.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# ls -lh /srv/
total 4.8G
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 00:14 too_large_a_file
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 00:26 too_large_a_file_2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 02:34 too_large_a_file_3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 02:34 too_large_a_file_4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 02:35 too_large_a_file_5
```

The drive is clearly maxed out here as well.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8377344 1975040   6402304  24% /
devtmpfs         1920720       0   1920720   0% /dev
tmpfs            1809256       0   1809256   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1809256   82192   1727064   5% /run
tmpfs            1809256       0   1809256   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb1       4183040 4183020        20 100% /mnt
tmpfs             361852       0    361852   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0      10475520 5055864   5419656  49% /srv
```

The md5sums are as follows for all the files and the original.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# md5sum too_large_a_file
e8154ef97a3eb2bd13aea04b823a4570  too_large_a_file

[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# md5sum /srv/*
e8154ef97a3eb2bd13aea04b823a4570  /srv/too_large_a_file
e8154ef97a3eb2bd13aea04b823a4570  /srv/too_large_a_file_2
e8154ef97a3eb2bd13aea04b823a4570  /srv/too_large_a_file_3
e8154ef97a3eb2bd13aea04b823a4570  /srv/too_large_a_file_4
154248d2eeaf5791dfc8199e51daadbc  /srv/too_large_a_file_5
```

<s>I'll add this is something clearly affecting the system, because adding a sixth file crashed it.</s> *Note: after the copy finished the system became responsive again.*

**Edit 2:** Added `du` information.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# du -h /srv/*
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file_2
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file_3
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file_4
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file_5
```

**Edit 3:** Memory information
I tested this by removing the files that "overran" the buffer, then copying one back and dropping caches and seeing what happened.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# rm /srv/too_large_a_file_5
rm: remove regular file ‘/srv/too_large_a_file_5’? y
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# cp too_large_a_file /srv/too_large_a_file_5
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  2.2G  5.9G  28% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   97M  1.7G   6% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G  4.0G   20K 100% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0       10G  4.9G  5.2G  49% /srv
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# free -m && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3533          93        1210         104        2229        3091
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3533          94        3281         104         157        3183
Swap:             0           0           0
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  2.2G  5.9G  28% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G  105M  1.7G   6% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G  4.0G   20K 100% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0       10G  4.9G  5.2G  49% /srv
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# md5sum /srv/too_large_a_file_5
154248d2eeaf5791dfc8199e51daadbc  /srv/too_large_a_file_5
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# du -ah /srv/
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file_2
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file_3
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file_4
982M    /srv/too_large_a_file_5
4.8G    /srv/
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# ls -lh /srv/
total 4.8G
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 00:14 too_large_a_file
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 00:26 too_large_a_file_2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 02:34 too_large_a_file_3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 12:16 too_large_a_file_4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 982M Aug 29 12:27 too_large_a_file_5
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]#
```

**Edit 4:** Memory information continued
I was suspicious of my findings to I did one more test, it appears to be a bit enlightening. It seems that the file does get changed after caches are dumped, the `md5sum` output does update.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# rm /srv/too_large_a_file_5
rm: remove regular file ‘/srv/too_large_a_file_5’? y
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# cp too_large_a_file /srv/too_large_a_file_5
(reverse-i-search)`m': r^C/srv/too_large_a_file_5
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# md5sum /srv/too_large_a_file_5
e8154ef97a3eb2bd13aea04b823a4570  /srv/too_large_a_file_5
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]#
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]#
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# md5sum /srv/too_large_a_file_5
e8154ef97a3eb2bd13aea04b823a4570  /srv/too_large_a_file_5
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# free -m && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3533          93         298         104        3141        3091
Swap:             0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3533          93        3274         112         166        3175
Swap:             0           0           0
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# md5sum /srv/too_large_a_file_5
154248d2eeaf5791dfc8199e51daadbc  /srv/too_large_a_file_5
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  2.2G  5.9G  28% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G  113M  1.7G   7% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G  4.0G   20K 100% /mnt
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0       10G  4.9G  5.2G  49% /srv
```

After reboot

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# mount /mnt/file /srv/
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  2.2G  5.9G  28% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   17M  1.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb1      4.0G  4.0G   20K 100% /mnt
/dev/loop0       10G  4.9G  5.2G  49% /srv
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]#
```

**Edit 5:** Sync information

It appears that mounting the file in a sync fashion generates the error.

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# mount -odefaults,sync /mnt/file /srv/
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
..snip..
/dev/xvdb1 on /mnt type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/mnt/file on /srv type xfs (rw,relatime,sync,seclabel,wsync,attr2,inode64,noquota)
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# cp too_large_a_file /srv/too_large_a_file_5
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# cp too_large_a_file /srv/too_large_a_file_5
cp: error writing ‘/srv/too_large_a_file_5’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/srv/too_large_a_file_5’: Input/output error
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# ls /srv/
too_large_a_file  too_large_a_file_2  too_large_a_file_3  too_large_a_file_4  too_large_a_file_5
```

Comment: It might be useful to add which Linux distribution, version and kernel version this happens on.

Comment: @JonathanClarke Added per your request.

Comment: Have you restarted the system and checked the file contents after that? Do you have enough memory on the box so that the file contents could be cached completely? Anyway, I think this is one corner-case bug which hasn't been taken care of in the kernel / filesystem implementation. After all, there are many layers over here..

Comment: Caches were a good point, I tested by dumping cache and checking the files again. It hasn't appeared to affect the file outputs (see edit 3).

Comment: I've also added an edit 4, it appears that syncing the drive does change the offending file in someway, but not in way that is detected by any of the tools.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen if you make your comment an answer, I can accept it. It appears that caches were the "problem." When I mount the drive with the `sync` option enabled I get an IO error on write. It's an interesting edge case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have enough memory on the box so that the file contents could be cached completely? Anyway, I think this is one corner-case bug which hasn't been taken care of in the kernel / filesystem implementation. After all, there are many layers at work over here.

Comment: To flesh this answer out a bit, Tero got me on the right track. File system caching was causing the issue. Updating my mount to be a `sync` mount solved the problem (although not necessarily in a great way, I'm not sure about the implications about performance).

Answer (score 0):

"Now, when I attempt to create a file that should overrun the host drive, it will also write correctly and not report an error."

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/srv/too_large_a_file
```

Yes it will write correctly, since you are writing zeros which is what the sparse file is unless it is overwritten to something else, hence what you have done here writes nothing to the sparse file. If you wrote something other than zeros, the write would fail.

cp and rsync may, depending on os and kernel versions preserve sparseness.

Comment: This was a good thought, I've replicated my findings with using a file filled with ones. Please see the edits.

Comment: and what is the size of the file reported by du in each case?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: It appears that using `sync` works in the case of zero based files as well.
`[root@ip-172-31-61-147 ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/srv/too_large_a_file bs=1GiB count=5
dd: error writing ‘/srv/too_large_a_file’: Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 70.0273 s, 0.0 kB/s
`